Quantised optical cavities with non zero decay rate
The quantised electric field of an optical cavity can be described as a harmonic oscilator,
$$\hat{H}_{\mathrm{c}}=\hbar\omega_{\mathrm{c}}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}.$$
If the cavity mirrors are lossless then excitations in the cavity describe excitation of a single monochromatic photon at the cavities resonance frequency. If the cavity mirrors exhibit losses, a coherent state of the cavity will decay at a rate given by $\kappa$, and the cavity will be able to support frequencies over a linewidth of $2\kappa$ (i.e, light from external modes can be coupled into the cavity with a strength given by a Lorentzian function of linewidth of $2\kappa$).
My question is, in the case of a mirror with losses, does an excitation within the cavity correspond to a photon with a spectral distribution given by the Lorentzian distribution of light supported by the cavity?
A related question is, suppose light detuned from the cavity resonance by $\Delta$ is coupled into the cavity. $\Delta$ is close enough to zero such that a good amount may be coupled in, but far enough away such that photons at the cavity resonance are noticably different in energy to the injected photons. Does the cavity become excited by light at its resonance?
My instinct tells me this has something to do with the time-energy uncertainty relation, but I cant wrap my head around it just yet.
(any reading resources you can provide me with are also helpful)

It depends on which basis you work in.
In the Hamiltonian, the OP is only writing down a single degree of freedom, the "cavity mode". The decay, however, by definition occurs into different degrees of freedom. These degrees of freedom can be treated in different ways.
The most natural to comply with the single mode description is by an external continuum bath (see https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761) which couples to the single mode. This coupling then determines how broad in frequency an input photon can be to still significantly excite the mode. This is typically characterized by a single quantity: the spectral width of the cavity mode.
To contrast this argument: One can also directly work in a continuum basis (see e.g. https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.467). There, the concept of width is even more natural, but calculations are usually harder.

Because of the uncertainty principle, a photon with a perfectly defined wavelength must have an infinite lifetime. This requires lossless mirrors.
